# Storing visitor account info?

Tags: ecommerce, database

This might sound pretty simple and dumb but I need your help here

I am starting an eCommerce marketplace, I am pretty new to it so I just wanted to know when a visitor/ buyer registers on my site, all the details of his account ( not  credit card) other details like number, name, address, where will it be stored? in what database?

Answer (score 2):

It will be stored in what ever database you want.

Presumably you have a database that holds the items you are selling, in that case store the customer details in a table in that database.

In fact what you should have is two tables. One to hold the basic customer details (name etc.) and a second for addresses. That way you can have multiple addresses per customer (billing address, various shipping addresses) and share those addresses between customers so you don't end up with duplicate data in the system

You are correct in stating that you shouldn't store credit card details.